# Problem with User.remove, it says that it is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I'm trying to post users on /user with express.Router()
But it says that await User.remove is not a function.
Maybe i need to import some more features?
Here is code

```
import express from "express";
import User from "./Models/UserModel.js";
import users from "./data/users.js";
import Product from "./Models/ProductModel.js"


const ImportData = express.Router()

ImportData.post(
    "/user",
    async (req, res) => {
      await User.remove({});
      const importUser = await User.insertMany(users);
      res.send({ importUser });
    }
  );

ImportData.post("/products",async (req,res)=>{
    await Product.remove({});
    const importProducts = await Product.insertMany(products);
    res.send({ importProducts });
});

export default ImportData;
```

Here is error:

```
await User.remove({});
                 ^

TypeError: User.remove is not a function
    at file:///C:/react//frontend/Server/DataImport.js:12:18
```

UserModel.js:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

export default User;
```

I tried a lot, maybe here is another solving of this problem?
Thank u in advance

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of `UserModel.js`?

Comment: @JSONDerulo already added

Comment: `User.deleteMany({});`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object you are calling `remove()` on is a [Model](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#models). Looking at its documentation, there indeed is no `remove` function; the only function whose name hints at similar behavior I can find is the `deleteOne()` and `deleteMany()` function found in the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#deleting).

The `remove` function is part of a `Schema`, as seen [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schema.html#Schema.prototype.remove()) in the documentation. In your code, a `Schema` is only used in the `UserModel.js` file, to create the Model.

Answer (score 10):

In new mongoose versions, `document.remove()` is deprecated. Replace `remove()` with `deleteOne()` or `deleteMany()`.

Check the mongoose documentation's deprecation warning [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with one of my own projects where it said user.remove() is not a function and user.deleteOne() worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).